# Clang (OS X) requires "template" keyword in a particular nested declaration, while VS forbids it

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, c++11, clang

I am writing a cross-platform application in two compilers (Clang on Xcode v5.0.2, and Visual Studio 2012 Update 4) and I have run into a scenario in which the two compilers disagree about the required syntax for the use of the `template` keyword in a nested declaration.

Here is the code (boiled down to an easily reproducible test case):

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    template<typename U>
    struct InnerBase
    {};
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct Derived : public Base<T>
{
    // the "template" keyword is REQUIRED in Clang/OSX
    struct InnerDerived : public Base<T>::template InnerBase<U>
    {};

    // the "template" keyword is FORBIDDEN in Visual Studio 2012
    struct InnerDerived : public Base<T>::InnerBase<U>
    {};
};

int main()
{
    Derived<int, int>::InnerDerived foo;
}
```

As noted, the two compilers disagree about the use of the "template" keyword.

For Clang, when the `template` keyword is **not** included, the error is:

> Use 'template' keyword to treat 'InnerBase' as a dependent template
>   name

For Visual Studio, when the `template` keyword **is** included, the error is:

> 'Base::InnerBase' : use of class template requires template
>   argument list

I have looked at various other StackOverflow questions regarding the rules for use of the `template` keyword (for example, [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132)).  However, looking at this, and other similar questions, does not give me confidence in claiming that one compiler is correctly implementing C++11 and that the other is not.

(Note that Clang's error makes sense to me, while the VS error doesn't make much sense to me because it seems that I *am* including the template argument list.)

Which compiler is correct in this case?  Should the `template` keyword be included, or not, in the sample code above (for C++11 compliance)?

(Possibly I have not set the compiler settings correctly to use C++11 in one or the other case - in which case, my question still stands: which version of the code above is correct C++11 code?)

Comment: Test it against gcc to create a majority! :-) I _think_ clang is right in requiring the `template` keyword.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if VS disagrees with another compiler, then VS is wrong. This is accurate to about 90-95%.

Comment: GCC agrees with clang.

Comment: In particular with respect to templates and lookup, VS has a tendency not to get it right as it has been dependent on single lookup (rather than two phase lookup) for a long period of time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the relevant clause is 14.2 (temp.names) paragraph 4:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->`in a postfix-expression or after a nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the object expression of the postfix-expression is type-dependent or the nested-name-specifier in the qualified-id refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`.

I think that says that `template` is required. Following up with [DyP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp)'s comment, it seems certainly wrong to reject the keyword even if it isn't required (paragraph 5 of the same clause):

> A name prefixed by the keyword `template` shall be a template-id or the name shall refer to a class template. [Note: The keyword `template` may not be applied to non-template members of class templates. —end note] [Note: As is the case with the `typename` prefix, the `template` prefix is allowed in cases where it is not strictly necessary; i.e., when the nested-name-specifier or the expression on the left of the `->` or `.` is not dependent on a template-parameter, or the use does not appear in the scope of a template.—end note].

Comment: For fairness with VC++, this is a Standard defect because the grammar makes the code that has the "template" in it ill-formed. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1710

Comment: I should also comment on Richard's sayings in the DR "although the relevant wording in 14.2 [temp.names] paragraph 4 only requires it in a qualified-id, not in a class-or-decltype". Often it is the case that the Standard refers to qualified-id, when it actually means something like "qualified name". See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c++.moderated/_DrR6f-92Yg/yw5te3CMHW8J and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c++/q1kk9ekIJXI

Comment: Funny, here's an old dupee of 1710: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#314

Answer (score 5):

Clang is correct, `Base<T>` is dependent on a template parameter. This is yet another symptom of Visual C++ not implementing two-phase name lookup for templates.